# ExtJS GridPanel Entire Row Click

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

I have a grid and I need to make the line selected, when the user clicks anywhere on it, that is, today I have a checkbox to select the line, I was wondering if there is any configuration or something of the Ext itself that give me that.

Today i have this:
[image]

And i want to select the row, when user clicks anywhere on it!

Basically the same as pressing the keyboard control (ctrl) and clicking on the line

Comment: Depends on the version you're using. If you're using the checkbox selection model, the default is to allow a row select to trigger the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox selection model has property [checkSelector](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-cfg-checkSelector) (sorry you dont specified framework version). set `checkSelector: '.x-grid-row'` to solve your problem

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32g9